# Page navigation/workflow framework in Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, workflow, zk

I've been tasked to investigate page navigation/workflow for a system, basically our architects call this 'orchestration'. We use ZK as our view/model and controller framework and would like to plug-in workflow/navigation capability.

I've investigated Spring Webflow/MVC, but this seems way to verbose and complex requiring the developer to do way too much XML 'sit-ups'.

Is there some open-source, developer friendly framework that can just plug-in to any other UI framework and provide simple, concise page navigation (besides Spring Webflow)? Possibly making use of annotations, simple XML or database backed configuration?

thanks in advance.

Comment: +1 for xml 'sit-ups' in spring ;D

Comment: @ThomasJungblut http://www.recursion.org/2006/1/20/xml-situps

Comment: Have you found a viable solution to implement a workflow using a ZK-native way?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check Apache Struts? But as far as I know Spring Webflow is a nice one!

See these links
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13226_01/workshop/docs81/doc/en/core/index.html
http://struts.apache.org/index.html

Comment: Thanks Dave, Struts 1 was a dog, will check out Struts2.

Comment: Struts2 kinda works with ZK, but still has some issues. We will probably develop our own screen orchestration.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for the same few days ago. Thus I would like to share thing till i found. I would like to tell you to refer [zkjbpm](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zkjbpm/) which integrates JBPM and ZK. For workflow designing please refer petals,activiti workflow designer which are based on BPMN 2.0 Specifications. Also refer to SVG for creating your own workflow designing tool in zk.